# Android custom filter works great in vertical mode but doesn't filter in horizontal mode

Tags: android, spinner

My custom filter and adapter for an autocompletetextview works great when the app is vertical but in horizontal mode the spinner provides a list that doesn't change when one types in text.  When you click done on the softkeyboard, the vertical filter works perfectly.  My question is, how do you disable the spinner that appears above the softkeyboard and below the textview?

Answer (score 0):

are you asking for this.. [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Comment: No, but thank you.  I implemented my custom adapter and filter which get passed to a drop down list in vertical orientation and horizontal orientation.  The only difference is there seems to be a default spinner that pops up with the soft keyboard that is populated with my list, however, typing letters doesn't narrow the spinner list.  My thought was just to hide the spinner, if that were possible.

Comment: is it buy any chance that onOrientationChange is affecting you activity's state.

Comment: I don't think so.  Maybe I have to override the spinner that pops-up by default when you the softkeyboard is launched? The other option is to figure out how to tie my filstered results to both the drop down list and this spinner?